# React update the style of a div within an array of divs

Tags: css, reactjs, algorithm

I'm trying to make a sorting algorithms visualiser where there are bars and when the play button is clicked a specific sorting algorithm will be animated with the bars moving.

I have made an array of divs and set the background color of the bars. I made another array to match the length of the bars so when I sort the array of lengths I can sort the array of bars at the same time.

```
 const {bars, setBars} = useContext(BarsContext)
 const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
        setData([])
        setBars([])
        for(let i=0; i<=value; i++){
            const randomLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500)
            setBars(current => [...current, <div className="bar" ref={ref} style={{ height: randomLength, backgroundColor: "#add8e6" }}></div>])
            setData(data => [...data, randomLength])
        }
    }, [value])

  const runAlgorithm = () => {
        if(active == "bubble"){
            bubbleSort()
        } else if(active == "merge"){
            Mergsort()
        } else if(active == "selection"){
            Selectionsort()
        }
    }
   const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));



    const bubbleSort = async() => {
        let count = 0
        console.log(data)
        for(let i=0; i<bars.length; i++){
            for(let j=0; j<bars.length; j++){
            console.log(bars[j].props.style.backgroundColor)
            bars[j].props.style.backgroundColor = "red"
            bars[j+1].props.style.backgroundColor = "red"
              if(data[j] > data[j+1]){
                let temp = data[j+1]
                data[j+1] = data[j]
                data[j] = temp
                setData([...data])

                let temp2 = bars[j+1]
                bars[j+1] = bars[j]
                bars[j] = temp2
                setBars([...bars])
                await sleep(100);
              }
              count +=1
              console.log(count)
            }
          }
          console.log(data)
    }
```

In the sorting algorithm I have tried to change the background color to red but an error message pops up saying it cannot access props undefined even though when I log it, it is there.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are filling `bars` array with DOM elements of your bars, expecting they have some props. But they are not components, so you can just access the style property of each DOM element

And besides of that, I would rather use `data` array to render DOM elements with needed atributes than storing DOM elements in some array

Comment: If I was to use the data array how would I be able to change the background color of the bars when sorting as it's just an array of heights

Comment: 1. you can store the hightlighted element index in state 2. you can extend array of heights to an array of objects `{height, color}`